# Why something later in the code is executed (done) before previous command?

Tags: android

This is a bit of my torch app code.

```
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.2);
    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    camera.setParameters(p);
    camera.startPreview();
```

When application is running first the LED lights and after that with 1-2 second lag the image is changed.

```
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.1);
    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    camera.setParameters(p);
    camera.stopPreview();
```

But when i'm turning off the light the image change immediately.

Can someone help me? The new image shows that light is on so this lag look aweful.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs for  ImageView.setImageResource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29):

> This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can
>   cause a latency hiccup. If that's a concern, consider using
>   setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) or
>   setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) and BitmapFactory instead.

Comment: Sorry but I'm completely newbie. Can you say something more how I can use one of this solutions?